# Getting a property from two NSManagedObjects, and saving it as the property of another

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

In a new version of my application I want to merge two properties on two different NSManagedObjects and use it on a relationship of both of these objects.

For example, I have an object 'Document' (which in an updated version now has the property 'title'), this object is related to a 'book' and a 'appointment' who both used to have the property 'title'.

The Core Data programming guide is very confusing to read and from what I can make, I have to perform/override a custom migration.

My model gets migrated nicely, except for this piece of data. Can anyone push me in the right direction to update this property?

Thanks!

Here's what I'm getting at:

**My old model**

```
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            +--------------------+
|        Book        |            |     Appointment    |            |      Document      |
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            +--------------------+
| - Title            |            | - Title            |            | - Date Added       |
| - Date Added       |            | - Date Added       |            | - Date Modified    |           
| - Date Modified    |            | - Date Modified    |            +--------------------+
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            |  (Relationships)   |
|  (Relationships)   |            |  (Relationships)   |            +--------------------+
+--------------------+            +--------------------+
```

**My new model**

```
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            +--------------------+
|        Book        |            |     Appointment    |            |      Document      |
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            +--------------------+
| - Date Added       |            | - Date Added       |            | - Title            |                                                       
| - Date Modified    |            | - Date Modified    |            | - Date Added       |
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            | - Date Modified    |
|  (Relationships)   |            |  (Relationships)   |            +--------------------+
+--------------------+            +--------------------+            |  (Relationships)   |
                                                                    +--------------------+
```

How do I move my data from my old model, into the new model?

Comment: Not clear how you want the titles merged. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: A 'book' and an 'appointment' each have a title. A document is related to either a 'book' or an 'appointment'. I want to set the documents title, to its corresponding  book or appointment.

Comment: Updated question with visual format